# Bounded sequence, converging subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a sequence $f_n$ that is uniformly bounded in $n$ in some space Banach space $X$. Now suppose $X\subset Y$ for some Banach space $Y$ and $X$ is even compactly embedded into $Y$. Then I know $f_n$ has a subsequence that converges in $Y$ to some $f\in Y$. How do I show that I even have $f\in X$ (i.e. does it follow that $X$ is closed as subspace of $Y$)? Does the convergence also holds in $X$?
I'm reading a paper and the authors just claim $f\in X$.

Comment: This is not true in general:
One can have continuous functions as uniform limits of differentiable functions. So $X$ space of continous diff functions, $Y$ space of continuous functions.

Comment: You're absolutely right! That's also what I was thinking. Not sure why the authors are claiming this.

Comment: how can a Banach space be a compact subset of another Banach space?

Comment: @daw Is the space of continuous differentiable functions a Banach space?

Comment: It can be proven that if two norms on $X$ induce the same topology, and if one of these norms is complete, then so is the other (I refer to the section on metrization in Chapter 1 of Rudin's Fundtional Analysis). So if $X$ is a Banach space and is embedded in another Banach space $Y$, then $X$ as a subspace of $Y$ is still a Banach space. Hence the subsequential limits of $(f_n)$ in $Y$ is in $X$.